# How to fix Error START_ARRAY token when deserializing Json with ModelMapper?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, modelmapper

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file in this format:

```
[
  ["AA", "GG", "1992/11/18"],
  ["BB", "DD", "2005/02/20"]
]
```

Using this class:

```
public class DataList {
    private List<String> att;
    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

doing:

```
DataList [] dataList= mapper.readValue(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + filename), DataList [].class);
```

But I'm getting:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `org.example.DataList ` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 2, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])
```

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jackson doesn't know how to map array of strings to `DataList` object. So you should just add `@JsonCreate` on `DataList` constructor to show Jackson what to use for the conversion.

```java
public class DataList {

    private List<String> att;

    @JsonCreator
    public DataList(List<String> att) {
        this.att = att;
    }

    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the same error happened again.

Comment: @jimmy, please, specify your `Jackson` version. Also you could try running your code with just a raw String (not reading json from file), to be sure that it's not a part of problem.

Comment: There was a typo, your solution works! Thanks!