# How to deserialize JSON file starting with an array in Jackson - with Annotations only?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json response that looks like this:

```
[
    { "name":"A" },
    { "name":"B" }
]
```

I have Java classes representing a single `ResponseDto` and contains a List of `Person`:

```
public class GetPersonsResponseDto {
    public List<Person> persons;
}

public class Person {
    public String name;
}
```

I would like to deserialize the by JSON using `ObjectMapper` but without use of a custom Deserializer and without collection type (no `Persons[].class` or `TypeReference<List<Person>>(){}`). What I really want is

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(in, GetPersonsResponseDto.class);
```

But I get:

```
jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not deserialize instance of com.project.my.GetPersonsResponseDto out of START_ARRAY token
```

I tried several Annotations but without success.

Comment: what annotations did you try?

Comment: `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)`, `@JsonValue`, `@JsonProperty` without change

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846490/how-to-fix-error-start-array-token-when-deserializing-json-with-modelmapper

Comment: thanks for pointing us in the right direction kerbermeister, all the searches i was making either didnt have a solution or was using custom deserializer and was quite convoluted

Comment: @kerbermeister I also tried `@JsonCreator` but it did not work. Now I tried again on my non-corporate machine and it works! Maybe there is a difference in the versions. Please post it as answer.

Comment: you're welcome, posted an answer, however, I agree it depends on the version of jackson you're using

Comment: @kerbermeister so i might not able to use this approach because I'm tied to the platform versions in corporate field. Maybe someone knows an alternative to `@JsonCreator`?

Comment: I'll try to research this

Comment: Seems to work on both machines/versions. Tested 2.13.4, 2.14.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is quite simple to serialize your models to the target json, but might be tricky to deserialize.

So, the solution for deserialization in this case could be using `@JsonCreator` annotation from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` package above constructor:

```
@Data
public class GetPersonsReponseDto {

    public List<Person> persons;

    @JsonCreator // use this annotation for deserialization on constructor
    public GetPersonsReponseDto(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public GetPersonsReponseDto() {
    }
}
```

However, it might not work with some versions of jackson.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm able to add annotations to fields, getter, setter or class only because of the limitations of code generation framework for beans. I'm looking for an alternative.